# MDX query to compare different years

Tags: mdx, mondrian

I am new to MDX and wondered if it is possible to create a query that shows a Sales amount per Year and per Month on two different axes, even if the sales date is a single dimension.

Something like:

```
Sales    |   2010    |    2011    |   Diff   
---------+-----------+------------+----------
Jan      |  1234,00  |  2345,10   |  +80%
Feb      |    ...
...
```

**EDIT:** Added mondrian to tags, because there seem to be possibilities with other MDX implementations not available in mondrian.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem can be solved with the ParallelPeriod function:

```
WITH MEMBER [Measures].[Einheiten Vorjahr] 
  AS '(ParallelPeriod([Year],1),
      [Measures].[quantity])'
SELECT {[Measures].[quantity],[Measures].[Einheiten Vorjahr]} ON COLUMNS,
       [date].[2010].children on rows
FROM salesorderitems
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes the solution is around [calculated members](http://www.iccube.com/support/documentation/mdx_tutorial/calculated_members.html) :

Let's imagine your initial MDX looks like :

```
Select
 { [Calendar].[Year].[2010],[Calendar].[Year].[2011] } on 0,
 { [Calendar].[Months].members } on 1
from [Cube]
```

You can add a calculated member in the [Year] hierarchy :

```
With
 Member [Calendar].[Year].[Diff] as [Calendar].[Year].[2011] / [Calendar].[Year].[2010]-1, FORMAT_STRING='percent'
Select
 { [Calendar].[Year].[2010],[Calendar].[Year].[2011], [Calendar].[Year].[Diff] } on 0,
 { [Calendar].[Months].members } on 1
from [Cube]
```

You can also add a more elegant and flexible solution, by using [utility or statistical dimensions](http://www.iccube.com/support/documentation/user_guide/schemas_cubes/dim_stats.html).  Those dimension instead of holding data define transformations / functions and the output will not be exactly the one you're looking, but it's an interesting concept.

Comment: Sadly I get: Mondrian Error:Hierarchy '[date]' appears in more than one independent axis. Thanks anyway, I didn't know some implementations are more pickier than others here.

Comment: I guess [Calendar].[Months] is not a hierarchy but a level, that's why you might get this error (no Mondrian specific). MDX is sometimes too smart: You can try [Einheiten Vorjahr] without [Measures] it works (not sure for Mondrian). It's an issue in MDX without knowing the model you can't be sure of what it is (dimension, hierarchy, level, member). Alles besten mit deine erste Shritte in MDX

Comment: for info, [Calendar].[Months] if it's not a hierarchy the parser will try a level, if not a level it will try to find a member..